# Find $\lim_ {x \to 0+} (\frac{\tan x}{x})^{1/x^2}$ using L Hopital's Rule.

Tags: real-analysis

Please help me to find $$\lim_{x \to 0+}\left (\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{1/x^2}$$ using L Hopital's Rule.

Comment: You _have_ to do this with l'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: Take logarithms ...

Comment: not getting....

Comment: @Mathan show us your work so we see where you are not getting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluating immediately results in an indeterminate form of the kind "$1^{+\infty}$"; you need "$\frac{0}{0}$" or "$\frac{\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$" to apply l'Hôpital's rule.

Using the identity  $x=e^{\ln x}$ (for $x>0$), allows you to transform this into an indeterminate form of the kind "$\frac{0}{0}$", to which you can apply l'Hôpital's rule:
$$\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\exp\left(\ln\left(\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)\right)=\exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)}{x^2}\right)$$
Now finding the initial limit is reduced to finding:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)}{x^2} \tag{$*$}$$
and taking the exponential afterwards.

You can apply l'Hôpital's rule to $(*)$ but it seems to me that could get rather messy.

Alternatively, if you're allowed to do this, using a (partial) series expansion for $\tan x$ and then for $\ln(1+\ldots)$ is very easy.